# In codedUi how can I get values from a column in runtime, whereas <td>/<tr> is not gonna identified by search propertis Id?

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

Say any table defined under any div. div and table have unique id but under it's tr tag and td tag having no id. How can I get runtime values inside td tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Row Index and Column Index of the `<td>` you are looking for.

```
        var yourCell = new HtmlCell(TheTableControl);
        yourCell .SearchProperties.Add(HtmlCell.PropertyNames.RowIndex, rowIndex, PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo);
        yourCell .SearchProperties.Add(HtmlCell.PropertyNames.ColumnIndex, columnIndex, PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo);
```

Comment: Think about the possibilities of just using a linq statement on TableControl.GetChildren() finding all the cells with a particular column index besides the header cell. Then it would be easy to have all the data he needs with one line of code.

Comment: You could implement it anyway you'd like I'm just pointing out the search properties exist, and to use them for what he wants.